# Switching the first set of values in my row with the column names (IronPython)

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

So I've got my data table structured like

```
ColumnName1 | ColumnName2 | ColumnName3
------------|-------------|------------
value1      |value2       |value2
```

How would I change my column names to the values, so if I want to change "ColumnName1" to "value1" how would I do that using an **ironpyton** script. All I know so far is how to loop through the column names:

```
for col in Document.Data.Tables[myTable].Columns:
```

but I am not sure how would i switch out my data. Then delete row 1.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: Cleaner version of my code, that doesn't have hard coded columns, is available in my answer below ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put dataTable as a data table parameter. First, let's get the new column names :

```
# Imports
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

cursor1 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dataTable.Columns[0])
cursor2 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dataTable.Columns[1])
cursor3 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dataTable.Columns[2])

#iterate through table column rows to retrieve the value of the first line
for row in dataTable.GetRows(cursor1,cursor2,cursor3):
    value1 = cursor1.CurrentValue
    value2 = cursor2.CurrentValue
    value3 = cursor3.CurrentValue
    break
```

Then retrieve the current column names and replace them by new column names :

```
oldColName1 = dataTable.Columns[0].Name
oldColName2 = dataTable.Columns[1].Name
oldColName3 = dataTable.Columns[2].Name
dataTable.Columns[0].Name = value1
dataTable.Columns[1].Name = value2
dataTable.Columns[2].Name = value3
```

Now lets replace the values by the old column names (you can remove this part if you don't want this feature)

```
for row in dataTable.GetRows(cursor1,cursor2,cursor3):
    cursor1.CurrentValue = oldColName1
    cursor2.CurrentValue = oldColName2
    cursor3.CurrentValue = oldColName3
    break
```

---

## Edit for op request in comments

```
# Imports
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

cursors = []
nbcol = dataTable.Columns.Count

for x in range(nbcol):
    cursors.append(DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dataTable.Columns[x]))


#iterate through table column rows to retrieve the value of the first line
values = []

for row in dataTable.GetRows(*cursors):
    for x in range(nbcol):
        values.append(cursors[x].CurrentValue)
    break

oldColNames = []

for x in range(nbcol):
    oldColNames.append(dataTable.Columns[x].Name)
    dataTable.Columns[x].Name = values[x]

for row in dataTable.GetRows(*cursors):
    for x in range(nbcol):
        cursors[x].CurrentValue = oldColNames[x]
    break
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is there a way to make it so I don't need to hard code the amount of columns in my table?

Comment: I love you, you're the best! One last question(I know this isn't part of the original question, I've already accepted your answer and you don't need to answer this if you don't want to), but is there a way to delete the first row as well?

Comment: Probably by adding these lines at the end of the script, note that I'm unsure about the 0, it may be a 1 instead, and ";" stands for new line :
rowsToFilter=IndexSet(dataTable.RowCount,False); rowsToFilter.AddIndex(0); dataTable.RemoveRows(RowSelection(rowsToFilter))